# Transposing JSON array values to rows in Stream Analytics yields no output

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I'm streaming JSON input from blob storage.  Most data in the JSON is stored as name/value pairs in an array.  I need to send each input as a single output where each name/value pair is transposed to a column in the output.  I have code that works when using the "Test" feature while editing the query.  However when testing live, only the debugblob1 output receives data.

Why would the the live test work different from the query test?  Is there a better way to transpose array data to columns?

Note: The array's name/value pairs are always the same, though I don't want a solution that depends on their order always being the same, since that is out of my control.

**QUERY**

```
-- Get one row per input and array value
WITH OneRowPerArrayValue AS
(SELECT
    INPUT.id AS id,
    ARRAYVALUE.ArrayValue.value1 AS value1,
    ARRAYVALUE.ArrayValue.value2 AS value2
FROM
    [inputblob] INPUT
    CROSS APPLY GetElements(INPUT.arrayValues) as ARRAYVALUE),

-- Get one row per input, transposing the array values to columns.
OneRowPerInput AS
(SELECT
    INPUT.id as id,
    ORPAV_value1.value1 as value1,
    ORPAV_value2.value2 as value2
FROM
    [inputblob] INPUT
    left join OneRowPerArrayValue ORPAV_value1 ON ORPAV_value1.id = INPUT.id AND ORPAV_value1.value1 IS NOT NULL AND DATEDIFF(microsecond, INPUT, ORPAV_value1) = 0
    left join OneRowPerArrayValue ORPAV_value2 ON ORPAV_value2.id = INPUT.id AND ORPAV_value2.value2 IS NOT NULL AND DATEDIFF(microsecond, INPUT, ORPAV_value2) = 0
WHERE
    -- This is so that we only get one row per input, instead of one row per input multiplied by number of array values
    ORPAV_value1.value1 is not null)

SELECT * INTO debugblob1 FROM OneRowPerArrayValue

SELECT * INTO debugblob2 FROM OneRowPerInput
```

**DATA**

```
{"id":"1","arrayValues":[{"value1":"1"},{"value2":"2"}]}
{"id":"2","arrayValues":[{"value1":"3"},{"value2":"4"}]}
```

Comment: Have you tried kicking the "raw", untransformed input to a debug sink? If it works with test data and not live, first thing I'd rule out is unanticipated differences in data format.

Comment: I was testing by manually uploading the data to the blob storage input source, so I'm in control of the data.  I spoke with MS support and they can reproduce it but not explain it, so perhaps it's a bug.  I'm giving up for now!

Answer (score 0):

See my generic example below. I believe this is what your asking; where you have a JSON object that contains an Array of json objects.

```
    WITH MyValues AS
(
   SELECT   
   arrayElement.ArrayIndex,  
   arrayElement.ArrayValue  
   FROM Input as event  
   CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.<JSON Array Name>) AS arrayElement 
)
SELECT ArrayValue.Value1, CAST(ArrayValue.Value2 AS FLOAT) AS Value
INTO Output
FROM MyValues
```